# How to change border color of a view dynamically in Titanium

Tags: javascript, colors, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am new to Titanium and I am trying to change the border color of a view  through my .js file.

**XML File**

```
<View id="container" autoStyle="true" />
```

**TSS File**

```
#container: {
    top: '5dp',
    height: '50dp',
    left: '20dp',
    right: '20dp',
    borderWidth: '1dp',
    borderColor: 'blue'
}

.redBorder: {
    borderColor: 'red'
}
```

**.js File**

```
$.addClass($.container, "redBorder");
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: welcome to Titanium :) I'd like to point out you're not new to Appcelerator, that is just a company. The technology is called Titanium

Comment: ya I agree...thanks @RenePot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set property right away:

```
$.container.borderColor = 'red';
```

And that's it.